# Launching a frame from a dialog

Tags: java, swing, awt, jdialog

I am new to Swing hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a modal `JDialog` `d1` that contains a `JXHyperlink` that when I click it I should launch a `JFrame` `f` however when I do that the frame `f` goes behind the dialog `d1` so I figured I have to set the dialog `d1` to non-modal for this to work and it did!

```
   d1.setModal(false)
```

Now my problem is I have another "modal" dialog `d2` that has a button where when I click it, it should launch the dialog `d1` but for some reason `d1` goes behind `d2`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not allowed to launch a non-modal dialog from a modal dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Modal dialog is always shown on its parent. So, if you run any window (JFrame, non-modal JDialog) from modal dialog it is going behind.

The solution is if you want that dialog d(n) will be on dialog d(n-1) make it modal and set d(n-1) to be its parent.

So, in first case you can just change your JFrame to be JDialog an make it modal. Every time you start new instance of your dialog set the window that should be behind it as its parent. And try to avoid a lot of modal dialog boxes open at the same time. It is very annoying.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I kind of figured I have to do that, but I am trying to avoid making code changes like that because that JFrame also gets launched from other widgets and frames , this is all part of a big application.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth noting that modality changes cannot be made while the popup is visible.  You can change the visibility (setVisible(boolean)) of the popup and then change its modality, but if it is visible any modality changes will have no effect.